# Spinner with custom adapter doesn't disappear on selection

Tags: android, android-widget, android-spinner

I'm using a `Spinner` with a custom adapter class called `AlgorithmAdapter` and in principle everything's working fine, meaning the spinner popup appears and all containing views are properly inflated. However, what I'm not able to find out is how I "tell" the spinner when the selection is made. Of course I know about `setSelection()`, but that doesn't dispose the popup and return focus to the Activity.

So here's some of the relevant code:

In my activity, I create my adapter like this:

```
SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter = new AlgorithmAdapter(
    this,
    algorithmSpinner,
    R.layout.algo_spinner_item_detail,
    res.getStringArray(R.array.anaglyph_algorithm_titles),
    res.getStringArray(R.array.anaglyph_algorithm_descriptions),
    res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.anaglyph_algorithm_icons),
    algorithmSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()
);

algorithmSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

The constructor of `AgorithmAdapter` has the following signature:

```
public AlgorithmAdapter(Context context, Spinner spinner, int viewResourceId, String[] titles,
        String[] descriptions, TypedArray icons, int selectedPosition) {
```

The `getDropDownView()` method of `AlgorithmAdapter`:

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(viewResourceId, parent, false);
    }

    final ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.algoItemIcon);
    final TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.algoItemTitle);
    final TextView description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.algoItemDescription);
    final RadioButton radio = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.algoItemRadio);

    icon.setImageDrawable(icons.getDrawable(position));
    title.setText(titles[position]);
    description.setText(descriptions[position]);
    radioGroup.add(radio);

    /* it's essential to uncheck in case the positions do not match, because
     * the system reuses views that could still have a checked radio button */
    radio.setChecked(position == selectedPosition);

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // uncheck every other radio button
            for(RadioButton each : radioGroup)
                each.setChecked(false);

            // inform adapter and user that this button is selected now
            radio.setChecked(true);
            selectedPosition = position;

            spinner.setSelection(position);
        }

    });

    return convertView;
}
```

where `radioGroup` is a list of all RadioButtons from all drop down views in order to manage which one is currently checked and which ones have to be unchecked therefore.

That all works very well except for the fact that the popup doesn't close on `setSelection()` (which itself is working though).

I also tried to attach an `OnItemClickListener` to the Spinner and manage the selection stuff in there, but that throws an exception saying `setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner`, which is really annoying since it feels as if the framework stands in my way instead of helping me at this point. But anyway, that's the reason I have to pass the Spinner through to the adapter which I would be glad I had a different solution for…

So the only thing I'm missing is how I "close" or "dispose" the Spinners drop down. Could anybody help me with that? Is this even anywhere near the way do to it? It cannot be that difficult since writing custom adapters for Spinners is a pretty basic task.

EDIT: No idea if this helps, but maybe someone finds an error in the layout file of my drop down view item. `algo_spinner_item_detail.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/algoItemIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/algoIconDescription"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/algoItemRadio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/algoItemTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/algoItemIcon"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/algoItemIcon"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/algoItemDescription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/algoItemTitle"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/algoItemTitle"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/algoItemRadio" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How the heck do you close/dispose the f***ing Spinner drop down after you selected an item?

Comment: I can do that of course, but 1) that doesn't dispose the popup as well and 2) completely omitting the `convertView`'s `OnClickListener` leads to the `OnItemSelectedListener` not being called, since the selection only happens in `onClick`

Comment: The comment above was a response to a comment that has been deleted. It suggested using an `OnItemSelectedListener`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what did the trick for me (WARNING: don't show this code to your kids, you'd certainly go to hell for it):

In the `onClick` method of my `convertView` I put this line of code:

```
((View) parent.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent()).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

which not only gets rid of the LinearLayout in which the `convertView`s are contained, but also makes the `com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView` invisible, that was there to darken the Activity screen while a dialog/drop down is shown.

I'm still after a better solution.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. However, if I use your solution I ran into NPE, there are not that many 'parent' to go up. When I reduced to 2 getParent() calls, I ended up with another error "RootViewImpl" can't be cast to View. Have you found a better solution yet? Tis spinner weirdo really sucks.

Comment: Hey, I got an idea, that is generating a 'back' key after selecting the item, since that's how I dismiss the pop-up manually. Looking for how to do that now.