# Android, how to generate virtual 'back' key

Tags: android, key-events

Recently I ran into the same problem as here [Spinner with custom adapter doesn't disappear on selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917963/spinner-with-custom-adapter-doesnt-disappear-on-selection/12935973#comment40221125_12935973). 
All the part of selecting and return the selected item to the caller is solved. Now I just need to get rid of the Dropdown view.

My solution is:  generating a 'back' key event to dismiss the Dropdown view. How do I do that? 
Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like a hack, not a solution. It sounds like you have implemented the custom `Spinner` incorrectly... `Spinner`s should auto-dismiss the dropdown view themselves after selection. Programatically dispatching a back key event will only mask this bug.

Comment: @Alex so do you have a solution to the question in my link, I've searched SO several times and ending up with the same question withthout an answer. Cheers.

Comment: Maybe it would be best if you posted the code you used to implement the custom spinner and asked a question about the specific behavior you are trying to avoid.

Comment: @AlexLockwood this is the question as requested, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736930/spinner-with-custom-array-adapter-doesnt-allow-selecting-item