# Spinner with custom array adapter doesn't allow selecting item

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I use a custom array adapter for a spinner. However, when selecting an item in the dropdown list, the dropdown list stays there, and the spinner doesn't get updated, which is misbehaviour (compared to using a generic array adapter with string). This is the custom class. Am I missing anything? thanks.

```
public class CalendarNameAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AgendaLogic.ExternalCalendarInfo> {
    Context mContext ;
    ArrayList<AgendaLogic.ExternalCalendarInfo> mCalendarLayers;


    public CalendarNameAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<AgendaLogic.ExternalCalendarInfo> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        mContext = context;
        mCalendarLayers = objects;
    }



    @Override
    public void add(AgendaLogic.ExternalCalendarInfo object) {
        mCalendarLayers.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCalendarLayers.size();
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        Button button;
        TextView textView;
        public ViewHolder(Button _btn, TextView _tv){
            button = _btn;
            textView = _tv;
        }
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        View view =convertView;
        if (view==null){
            view =  View.inflate(mContext,R.layout.li_calendar_display, null);
            Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.calColor);
            TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.calName);
            view.setTag(new ViewHolder(button, name));

        }
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        viewHolder.button.setBackgroundColor(mCalendarLayers.get(position).color);
        viewHolder.textView.setText(mCalendarLayers.get(position).name);

        return  view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view = getView(position, convertView, parent);

        return  view;
    }



}
```

This is the usage, first init the spinner with mock data.

```
    public void initSpinner(){
        CalendarNameAdapter exteralCalAdapter = createAdapterWithString(this, "temp calendar");
        mExternalSpinner.setAdapter(exteralCalAdapter);

    }

    public   CalendarNameAdapter createAdapterWithString(Context context, String display) {
        ArrayList<AgendaLogic.ExternalCalendarInfo> list = new ArrayList<AgendaLogic.ExternalCalendarInfo>();
        list.add(new AgendaLogic.ExternalCalendarInfo(-1, display, 0xaabbcc));
        CalendarNameAdapter dataAdapter = new CalendarNameAdapter(context,
                0, list); //don't care about resource file, since we always use custom file, hence 0
        return dataAdapter;
    }
```

When I already load the data I need, I add it to the adapter:

```
private void setCalendarInfoToSpinner(ArrayList<AgendaLogic.ExternalCalendarInfo> calList, Spinner spinner) {
    CalendarNameAdapter adapter = (CalendarNameAdapter) spinner.getAdapter();
    adapter.clear();
    for (AgendaLogic.ExternalCalendarInfo info: calList)
        adapter.add(info);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up answering my own question for who needs it later. The solution is: check in the layout file of the list item. If there is a button, a radio, a checkbox, .etc. Set its focusability to false so that when you tap on the item, the list get  the tap, not that child view.

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Credit goes to another answer for similar question, but I can't seem to find it now.